# Parameter out of range, halt on chkdsk /r

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios, ntfs

### Background

I am the Web Designer and IT professional at a real estate company. Recently, one of our lawyers was receiving an error in her BIOS (Dell Vostro 230 MIG41R mobo, core duo) which said parameter out of range, may be an indication of hardware failure of something along those lines. A disconnect to the power occurred during `chkdsk /r`, which returned the ntfs_file_system stopcode.

### Attempted Fixes

I was able to remove the drive and put it in the IT computer and use `chkdsk /r` there after I used easeus data recovery software (which returned a parameter error vs. a formatting error). I was able to navigate the disk once more, prompting me to place it back into the old tower. chkdsk could not be cancelled at startup (must have pressed every key instead of any key). After about an hour and a half at "Scanning and repairing drive (C:): 13% complete", the system restarted, went into a Diagnostic menu, after which I entered `chkntfs /x c:` which allowed me to once again enter the PC.

### Course of Action

Clearly something is wrong with this PC, but it seems like a tough nut to crack. I have two bootable USBs for a 32-bit Windows 10 install (one FAT32, one NTFS although I believe the FAT32 one won't work on this BIOS for some reason), but I am apprehensive to use them as I've never done so before and my inability to find adequate documentation about exactly what gets overwritten is what has led me here. I've tried Error Checking which doesn't work, but the [drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0061YJABE) is a six year old drive (although I don't know how often it was used). I would prefer to get a new drive and migrate Windows vs. go through this arduous process again.

### tl;dr

parameter out of range in bios, `chkdsk /r` doesn't work, 3rd party software doesn't work, is HDD about to fail critically and how should I proceed (I can turn S.M.A.R.T. off in BIOS but seems counterintuitive).

Comment: clone the hard drive immediately.  Use clonezilla or even dd if you have to.  Once you have a backup then deal with.  Make 2 backups, in fact, and then you can chkdsk /r the backup and you still have a spare backup.

Comment: If you have to get data back, spinrite from grc.com will cost $70.  Professional recovery is $100-$3000.

Comment: If you are referring to a SMART warning then the drive is failing. Recover the data you need now, replace the drive, and reinstall Windows from scratch.

Comment: Physically destroy the old drive, *with prejudice*. [Someone mentioned *lawyer*, you don't want that old drive to be readable by anyone, ever.] Replace with new drive. Restore data from backup.

Comment: Probably going to pull the HDD out of a spare vostro to make due, as it has been collecting dust since it was purchased. Most likely going to store the hard drive in our parts bin. @Tetsujin thank you for reminding me about readability of the drive, as I probably would have just chucked it instead of saving it.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? You said you can read the data, so I guess it is not about data recovery. Are you asking how to dispose of the drive? Or what else?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It’s more of a general course of action. Like maybe someone could’ve provided me with a way to see which parameter is out of range, maybe it’s nothing or maybe I need to back up data with extreme prejudice or replace drive immediately, etc.

Comment: OK, again... What is the question exactly? We cannot answer if we don't get a clear question...

Comment: If your question is "what can/should I do", that's extremely broad given all of the possible underlying problems and an unclear current state, and there isn't enough diagnostic information here.

Comment: Parameter out of range means precisely that. As a web dev, perhaps you're thinking that means you can adjust the parameter and be all good, but no, this message results from checking your system's hardware, and one of those checks returns results that are outside of the correct operating range. The hardware is bad and the correct course of action is to replace the faulty hardware. What other steps (data recovery, etc) are appropriate depend on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter out of range means precisely that.

As a web dev, perhaps you're thinking that means you can adjust the parameter and be all good, but no, this message results from the computer running checks on its own hardware, and one of those checks returns results (parameters) that are outside of the correct operating range.

The hardware is bad and the correct course of action is to replace the faulty hardware. What other steps (data recovery, etc) are appropriate depend on the circumstances.

UPDATE:

Hard drives are not repaired. They are consumables.

If the data is super-important and cannot be retrieved without repairing the drive, the costs are quite high to repair the drive and recover the data, and the drive is only repaired FOR THE PURPOSE OF RECOVERING THE DATA. The drive is not repaired to be used again.

This is because physical hard drives (spinny-disks) are quite amazing pieces of equipment, wherein platters or metal or ceramic (glass) are spinning at many thousands of revolutions each minute while electro-mechanical armatures hold magnetic reading heads over the surface of the spinning platters at a distances only a small fraction of the width of a human hair. Even opening the drive in the safest of conditions will permanently alter the drive mechanisms and render it untrustworthy.

Faults and failures of drives are cause to never trust the drive again.

As your data is already saved, it is unnecessary to go through the process of attempting to repair the drive.

**Hard drives are cheap and they are easily replaced, and the cheap part you buy will be trustworthy, while the part repaired at great expense will not be.**

Comment: Is there any way to check which parameter, or am I better off backing up and trying to convince the powers at be for a replacement. *note: I’ve already backed up the data but my superiors would rather repair the drive if possible due to cost.

Comment: Waited a considerable amount of time before accepting as I was holding out to the hope that someone had a way to physically check the parameter (without taking it to a specialist). My girlfriends mother’s PC was on the receiving end of a blown fuse today, and lo and behold I receive a picture with the exact same error message. You’d never think I was a semester away from a BS in CS with all this IT work :p. Thanks for your help!